# Обработка выбора чекбокса на сервере

Tags: javascript, php, сервер, клиент-сервер, checkbox

Есть код на js на стороне клиента

```js
$input = $('input[name="available.all"]');
let editfullsqlcondition="";
let fullsqlquery="";

if $(input).on("change", function () {
    if $input.checked {
        pickupavailable="and goods.deliveryvalue=1";
        editfullsqlcondition+=pickupavailable;
        /*select * from goods where goods.deliveryvalue=1*/

} else{
    if editfullsqlcondition.includes("goods.deliveryvalue=1", 0) {
        if editfullsqlcondition.endsWith("goods.deliveryvalue=1")
            {
                fullsqlcondition=editfullsqlcondition.slice(0, editfullsqlcondition.length-" and goods.deliveryvalue=1".length);    

            }
        else    {

                fullsqlcondition=editfullsqlcondition.slice(0, editfullsqlcondition.indexOf("goods.deliveryvalue=1 and ", 

0))+editfullsqlcondition.slice(editfullsqlcondition.length - editfullsqlcondition.indexOf("goods.deliveryvalue=1 and ", 0) - editfullsqlcondition.length, 

editfullsqlcondition.length)
            }
}

}
}
console.log(fullsqlcondition);
);
```

Каким образом можно оформить передачу и обработку выбора чекбокса на стороне сервера? Событие `if $(input).on("change", function () { ... })` должно быть оформлено в рhp коде.

Answer (score -1):

```
if $(input).on("change", function () { 
        $.ajax({
      url:"/path_to_backend.php",
     type:"post",
    dataType:"JSON",
    data:{
    goodsdeliveryvalue:1,
    },success:function(data){
console.log(data)
}
    })
     })



        <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','userlogin','userpas','dbname');
if(isset($_POST['goodsdeliveryvalue'])){
$value  = $_POST['goodsdeliveryvalue'];
$sql = "select * from goods where goods.deliveryvalue=$value";
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
echo json_encode($row);
}
}
?>
```

через айакс можно получит то что нужно вот пример если будет вопроси напишите за акцент извините

Comment: а что вы скажите насчет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1256215/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5? В чем отличие (напишите какие файлы есть на клиенте и какие есть на сервере)?

Comment: а этот вопрос вы можете пояснить - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1256288/%d0%a1%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0

Comment: 2. Каким образом в вашем коде передается ответ клиенту (в виде переменной `$row`), вернее каков ее тип? Ведь `$row` представляет собой несколько пар ключ значение (`$row[column]=columnvalue`), а вы передаете ее в виде json (смущает, то что пар ключ/значение несколько, а не одно)

Comment: как только будете в онлайне (минусовал не я), напишите мне и ответьте мне по пунктам (сроки горят).