# Возвращение нескольких записей таблицы

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Есть код с [Обработка выбора чекбокса на сервере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1256215/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5)

```
            <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','userlogin','userpas','dbname');
if(isset($_POST['goodsdeliveryvalue'])){
$value  = $_POST['goodsdeliveryvalue'];
$sql = "select * from goods where goods.deliveryvalue=$value";
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
return json_encode($row);
}
}
?>
```

Возник вопрос:"Что делать, если необходимо передать несколько записей (`$row`) таблицы `goods`, ведь невозможно, чтобы функция имела несколько return-ов?"

Comment: Вернуть массив не вариант?

Comment: Собрать все записи в массив, закодировать массив в джсон и вернуть эту закодированную строку.

Answer (score 1):

Есть два способа это реализовать:

1. Это использовать функцию `mysqli_fetch_all`

   ```
    if(isset($_POST['goodsdeliveryvalue'])){

        $value  = $_POST['goodsdeliveryvalue'];

        $sql = "select * from goods where goods.deliveryvalue=$value";

        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {

            $row = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            return json_encode($row);
        }
    }
   ```
2. Это взять по одному и потом записать в массив, и вернуть:

   ```
        if(isset($_POST['goodsdeliveryvalue'])){

            $value  = $_POST['goodsdeliveryvalue'];

            $sql = "select * from goods where goods.deliveryvalue=$value";

            $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($query) >0) {

                $data = [];
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                    $data[] = $row;
                }

                return json_encode($data);
            }
        }
   ```

Рекомендую использовать первый вариант