# Парсинг json, переданного на клиент

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, json

Есть (часть ajax кода) [Возвращение нескольких записей таблицы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1257152/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b). Каким образом можно обратиться на клиенте к строкам и полям переменной `$row`? Ключ - номер строки (записи), а значение - это запись таблицы `goods`.

```
        if(isset($_POST['goodsdeliveryvalue'])){

        $value  = $_POST['goodsdeliveryvalue'];

        $sql = "select * from goods where goods.deliveryvalue=$value";

        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
            
            $row = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                        
            return json_encode($row);
        }
    }
```

```js
if $(input).on("change", function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/path_to_backend.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: {
      goodsdeliveryvalue: 1,
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: положите пожалуйста код в вопрос, а не ссылкой куда-то. спасибо

Comment: var row = JSON.parse(data); внутри success: function(data){}

Comment: @Jean-Claude как обратиться к конкретным строкам и столбцам переменной data?

Comment: ну так сначала распарсь json-строку, а потом обращайся через точку или квадратные скобки если массив https://learn.javascript.ru/json#json-parse